# INSERT-SELECTs and UPDATEs in race conditions

Tags: mysql, race-condition, simultaneous

#1: If I run

```
INSERT INTO foo SELECT MAX(X) FROM bar;
```

Can I be sure that I just inserted the maximum value of the `X` column from the `bar` table? That no other session managed to manipulate the `bar` table after the `SELECT` part was completed but before the `INSERT` was completed?

#2: If I run

```
UPDATE foo SET x = 0 WHERE y = 100;
```

when a clock hits 00:00 and the query takes 2 minutes, can I be sure that all rows that had `y = 100` at 00:00 has been updated? That no other session managed to change `y = 100` to `y = 80` before my query finished?

#3: This is related to #2. If at 00:01 another session does an `UPDATE`s to a row by changing `y = 99` to `y = 100`, does my previous query try to `UPDATE` this row?

Comment: Short answer is: **No**.  You cannot make such assumptions.

Comment: Use transactions to keep different sessions from interfering with each other.

Comment: And if `X` is an auto-increment ID of a table, you should use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to get the ID that was just inserted by the current session.

Comment: @Barmar How to use transactions to solve the issue?

Comment: Put `START TRANSACTION` at the beginning, and `COMMIT` at the end. Changes made during a transaction by one session will not be visible to other sessions.

Comment: @Barmar I don't get this. A single query is a transaction, so how does it differ if I put the query between "start transaction" and "commit"? Also, if the transaction level is READ UNCOMMITTED, I can do dirty reads so I might be using values that do not exist, right?

Comment: I thought you were trying to ensure consistency between the query that changed `MAX(bar.x)` and the one that inserts that into `foo`.

Comment: @Barmar Queries #1 and #2 are not related to each other in any way.

Comment: I never said they were. I assumed there was something *before* query #1 that updated `X`, and you wanted to ensure consistency between those two queries. Most likely, X is an auto-increment column, and you want to get the value that was just inserted.

Comment: @Barmar Okay, now I understand. My question was only a theoretical one so that I would understand better how database works. I decided to approach the problem by thinking what would happen if X was like a timestamp and max(X)s were inserted to foo table by single INSERT-SELECT queries. Then wondering would the values in foo table be in ascending order in the end (every value inserted is automatically equal or greater than any value that has been inserted before).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use explicit transactions, each query is treated as a transaction by itself. So a query that combines `INSERT` and `SELECT` like your #1 can depend on consistency. It's roughly equivalent to:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SET @max = (SELECT MAX(x) FROM bar);
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (@max);
COMMIT;
```

However, transactions don't make a snapshot of the entire database at the time the transaction starts. InnoDB uses per-record locking. So in #2 and #3, if you have session A updating `y` while session B perform the query you show, the records that B updates may or may not include the ones modified by A, depending on the relative order of those specific changes. MyISAM, on the other hand, uses table-level locks, so this should not be possible; whichever query starts first will lock the `foo` table, and the other query will wait for it to finish before it starts scanning the table.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not very good in English and the sentence "can depend on consistency" is giving me a big headache. Some say the word "consistency" means that a database does not allow invalid values to be inserted into the database (a string value into an integer column etc.). Some say it means that a database will not lose any data if power outage occurs. I suppose you did not mean either of these?

Comment: I meant "a consistent view of the table is guaranteed".

Answer (score 0):

Transactions are used to guarantee the state of the database.  Repeatable read so when read the max value you can read it again and again it will stay the same.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html#isolevel_repeatable-read

Then you set the transaction

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/set-transaction.html

Then your code update x = (select max(y) from z)

then you commit the transaction

I might have missed something but generally that's how its done for preceise reporting.

Comment: I think this is not a direct answer to my question but I understand the logic here. However, does this technique guarantee that at the time of the COMMIT the row is updated? To my knowledge another transaction may have deleted the row before the COMMIT.

Comment: @Croco The updated row will be deleted if that happens.